# How to change the default color of leaflet-routing-machine marker

Tags: angular, leaflet, marker, leaflet-routing-machine

I'am using ***leaflt-routing-machine*** plugin, and I need to change color of markers from blue to red, any suggestion please ?!

Answer (score 1):

I believe that this should work just fine

```
var redIcon = new L.Icon({
  iconUrl: 'https://cdn.rawgit.com/pointhi/leaflet-color-markers/master/img/marker-icon-red.png',
  shadowUrl: 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/0.7.7/images/marker-shadow.png',
  iconSize: [25, 41],
  iconAnchor: [12, 41],
  popupAnchor: [1, -34],
  shadowSize: [41, 41]
});



 L.Routing.control({
      waypoints: [
        L.latLng(57.74, 11.94),
        L.latLng(57.6792, 11.949)
      ],
      collapsible: true, // hide/show panel routing
      autoRoute: true, // possibility to take autoRoute
      language : 'fr', 
     // THIS IS ESPECIALLY WHAT YOU SHOULD ADD (createMarker):
      createMarker: function(i, wp, nWps) {
        return L.marker(wp.latLng, {icon: redIcon });
      },
      // ...
    }).addTo(this.map);
```